# When does Linux use publicly routable IPv4 address configured on a loopback interface?

Tags: linux, routing

Let's say, that I have a following routing table:

```
ffgrt@srv28:~$ ip -4 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 14.2.13.24/32 scope global lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 210.41.21.8/27 brd 210.41.21.31 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ffgrt@srv28:~$
ffgrt@srv28:~$ ip r
default via 210.41.21.30 dev ens3 onlink
210.41.21.0/27 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 210.41.21.8
ffgrt@srv28:~$
```

When is the `14.2.13.24` address(configured on loopback interface) used as a source address when I make connections out from the server? At least according to [this Source Address Selection guide](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-saddr-selection.html), the `14.2.13.24` address should be picked only if I manually bind to it because:

1. When I connect to `210.41.21.0/27` network, then the kernel will use the `src` hint from the chosen route path which means `210.41.21.8` in my case
2. When I connect to any other network than `210.41.21.0/27`, then kernel will choose the first address configured on the interface which falls in the same network as the destination address or the nexthop router. As the nexthop router is reachable via `ens3` and `ens3` has only `210.41.21.8` configured, then `210.41.21.8` is used.

Is the IPv4 address configured on `lo` interface used as a source address for outgoing connections only in case I manually bind to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why it's working

Linux, using the weak [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model), makes available any IP address assigned on any interface to the host as a whole and thus visible using any other interface.

So assigning an IP address on the loopback interface makes this IP address reachable, if other routing conditions allow to reach it (eg: a data center providing failover IP addresses has additional routes defined on its router(s) to the apparently unrelated IP addresses one can add to an host).

Here's what simply happens for your case (assuming the main interface is *eth0* and the gateway is *mygw*):

term1:

```
# ip address add 14.2.13.24/32 dev lo
```

term2 (running before the previous command):

```
$ ip -4 monitor
1: lo    inet 14.2.13.24/32 scope global lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
local 14.2.13.24 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 14.2.13.24 
^C
$ ip route get from 14.2.13.24 8.8.8.8 
8.8.8.8 from 14.2.13.24 via mygw dev eth0 uid 1000 
$ ip route get from 8.8.8.8 iif eth0 14.2.13.24
local 14.2.13.24 from 8.8.8.8 dev lo 
    cache <local> iif eth0
```

Routing works both ways, again, only if *mygw* is able to route this traffic too.

Assigning this IP address to *lo* just adds an other IP address to the host. The advantage is that it won't disappear when the main interface is brought down then up, nor one has to guess what are the interfaces available to assign this address to, thus simplifying some scripts: *lo* is always available and usually up.

---

### How to use this address without having to bind

As OP already wrote this address won't be used by default since the chosen route will use the primary IP address of the interface used to reach a destination, and *lo* will never be this interface (except for 14.2.13.24 itself where it's the hinted source).

It's still possible to tweak routes to choose this address as source for all or some destinations.

Example for one destination:

```
# ip route add 8.8.8.8 via mygw dev eth0 src 14.2.13.24
```

would make packets sent to 8.8.8.8 use by default 14.2.13.24 unless bound with an other IP address. I's possible to replace or override the existing routes and use this address as default source everywhere it matters.

---

### how applications can handle multiple addresses

If there's no route selecting the address as source, as client, one has to do an explicit bind to this address to send traffic from this address, using [*bind(2)*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/bind.2) before using for example [*connect(2)*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/connect.2).

As server (listening services), it depends:

- TCP services will behave as usual without any extra effort: they answer from the IP address they received a connection to.
- UDP services need additional care. This is not a case limited to having an address on *lo* but is for any multi-homed system having some or several IP addresses reachable from an other interface than the interface they were assigned to.

  - they can bind to this address and will receive packets only to this one, and replies will use the bound address as source. Without explicit binding, the main interface's address would be chosen (eg: 210.41.21.8 instead of 14.2.13.24) and the original client will reject the reply, because the address doesn't match the query.
  - if they still choose to bind to [*INADDR_ANY*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0#As_a_host_address), then the address which received the packet can't be known in advance (eg: was it 210.41.21.8 or 14.2.13.24?) and the kernel will still choose the main interface's IP address as reply by default. The application must then work differently: on Linux it should set the [*IP_PKTINFO*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ip.7#Socket_options) option on the UDP socket (using [*setsockopt(2)*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/setsockopt.2)) and then use [*recvmsg(2)*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/recvmsg.2#recvmsg()) to receive the ancillary information *in_pktinfo* telling on what local address it was received. The application can then reuse parts of these information using [*sendmsg(2)*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/sendmsg.2#sendmsg()) to tell the kernel what source address to send (without having to bind the socket). It's quite complex, here's an example on SO: [Setting the source IP for a UDP socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062205/setting-the-source-ip-for-a-udp-socket). (on *BSD, [*IP_RECVDSTADDR*](https://man.openbsd.org/ip.4) is used in the same way).

Answer (score 0):

No outgoing connections on `lo`. This cannot be a source address. There is no other device connected.

The only use case I could think of is when you have a web/other server on `14.2.13.24` and the same server software running on the current device.  You wish to test a configuration without experimenting on your online server.  Assign the server's address to `lo` and send requests to your local server instead of out via `ens3` (and make sure the routing is set up for that).  Then for your tests you can connect locally without needing to change DNS entries (or `/etc/hosts`).

After you are done testing locally you can transfer your settings to the real `14.2.13.24`, remove the address from `lo` and it will (hopefully) work.