# Multi-NIC RHEL host when would we want to force bind local NIC on TCP socket connect to remote server

Tags: routing

Fairly basic situation with RHEL6/7 host, and 3 eth* interfaces different IP addresses each, and a "normally" configured static route table.

Coding up in C a basic socket(2) + connect(2) to a remote IP/port destination.

In what situations would I normally not rely on the default kernel TCP/IP stack selection of a default IP source address, the one that matches the NIC connected to the router that is the gateway to reach the destination IP?

PS: I haven't written socket code since the late 90s :-)

Comment: Normally there's a need / usecase first, then code is written. Your question appears to me like "I want to write this, but I don't know what for".

Comment: anyway, take a look (at sources) at how bind9 and unbind (two DNS servers) handle UDP in a multi-homed case. They take two different approachs: one binds on all addresses, the other uses IP_PKTINFO.

Comment: See also my answer to a Q/A there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602832/when-does-linux-use-publicly-routable-ipv4-address-configured-on-a-loopback-inte/602885#602885